# How to retrieve snapshot's timestamp & build number from nexus using maven?

Tags: java, maven, nexus, snapshot

I want to get the latest snapshot version( with timestamp) of an artifact from Nexus3 using maven directly instead of using nexus3 API.

I know that Nexus3 REST API allows us to get this information directly using it is API or by parsing the metadata of the artifact.

But I do not want to use Nexus3 API cause it consumes my resources, neither to rely on parsing artifact metadata's on nexus3.

So **is there a way to get the latest snapshot direct URL, to download the artifact, or to get the snapshot timestamp using only maven commands**?

Comment: What do you need it for?

Comment: I want to have a direct url to download my latest snapshot, It is a specific use case where I have to use only a curl command to retrieve my artifact. I know  I can use Nexus3 REST API or maven:dependency-copy  or parsing nexus3 metadata direcly but I can not use theme in my case, the goal is to let maven give us this information.

Comment: Maven only knows about the artifact ID when it runs until it finishes the build.   Afterwards, it doesn't know anything.  The artifactory has the artifacts..................

If you want this information, store it somewhere when the build is successful.

Comment: What exactly does "Have Maven give us this information" mean?  You need to see the URL?  Get it in a file?  Have it magically transferred to a remote system?
--
Personally I would look into getting it from your CI system.  Any non-trivial development team effort will eventually break "my latest snapshot"

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I want to get the url that maven use to fetch the snapshot or the timestamp metadata of the snapshot.   
the purpose is to be able to download the snapshot using curl e.q:
To download url looks like this:  
**curl  https:*//nexus3/myrepo/com/hello/world/myapp-0.0.1-snapshot.$TIMESTAMP.jar**
But I am not able to get the timestamp of the snapshot using maven so I am asking if there is a way to get this infomation ?

Comment: @RidaeHAMDANI At this point I would suggest you look at the Maven sources to see how it works.  As Maven can print the URL of the artifacts it downloads, the information is there.

Comment: thanks @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

No.

There is no single download URL for the latest SNAPSHOT.

Your comment already mentioned the ways to find out about it (REST API, maven dependency plugin, parsing metadata).

If your desperately need such a URL, you need to build release versions.

Comment: I want to get the url that maven use to fetch the snapshot or the timestamp metadata of the snapshot.   
the purpose is to be able to download the snapshot using curl e.q:
The download url looks like this:  
**curl  https*://nexus3/myrepo/com/hello/world/myapp-0.0.1-snapshot.$TIMESTAMP.jar**
But I am not able to get the timestamp of the snapshot using maven so I am asking if there is a way to get this infomation ?

Comment: @RidaeHAMDANI I understood your intention. My answer is: No, there is not way to do that.